# Post json data in body to web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I get always null value from body why ?
I have no problem with using fiddler but postman is fail.

I have a web api like that:

```
    [Route("api/account/GetToken/")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseBody GetToken([FromBody] string value)
    {
        string result = value;
    }
```

My postman data:
[image]

and header:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't is need to be `GetToken([FromBody] string username, [FromBody] string password)`? Or you expected `value` to contain the whole json string?

Comment: i want to pass my data in body as json string formatted. What is the problem in my code ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

WebAPI is working as expected because you're telling it that you're sending this json object:

```
{ "username":"admin", "password":"admin" }
```

Then you're asking it to deserialize it as a `string` which is impossible since it's not a valid JSON string.

**Solution 1:**

If you want to receive the actual JSON as in the value of `value` will be:

```
value = "{ \"username\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"admin\" }"
```

then the string you need to set the body of the request in postman to is:

```
"{ \"username\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"admin\" }"
```

**Solution 2** (I'm assuming this is what you want):

Create a C# object that matches the JSON so that WebAPI can deserialize it properly.

First create a class that matches your JSON:

```
public class Credentials
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your method use this:

```
[Route("api/account/GetToken/")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseBody GetToken([FromBody] Credentials credentials)
{
    string username = credentials.Username;
    string password = credentials.Password;
}
```

Comment: I came here wondering if it deserialized the json body for you and am leaving a happy camper!

Answer (score 3):

You are posting an object and trying to bind it to a string.
Instead, create a type to represent that data:

```
public class Credentials
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/account/GetToken/")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseBody GetToken([FromBody] Credentials value)
{
    string result = value.Username;
}
```