# not getting right data in my backend from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to send data to my backend, but when it comes to backend it catches an expception thus returns error message. 
  I am assuming this is becuase data format from client side is somehow different than what I expected.

I expcect my backend to receive json string(I have other function that takes jsong string to object later).

What am I doing it wrong? I am aware that I can create modelling class for my data from client in my backend, but I need to work it without them and it shoud work as data are all string from my client 
  from client.

**client**

```
  //to backend 
  callServer() { 
    var data = JSON.stringify(test);
    //dispaly JSON like {"GradeA" : "23", "GradeB" : "45", "GradeC" : "22"} 
    console.log(data);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.appService.http.post('http://localhost:2717/api/testAPi/test', data, {headers: headers})
                        .subscribe(data => {console.log(data), (err) => console.error("Failed! " + err);
      })
  }
```

**backend**

```
public class testAPiController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public string test([FromBody] string body)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info(string.Format("data {0}", body));
            //convert to json object 
            return json_object;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message);
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

**Config**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Web API configuration and services
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "GET", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```

**Updated1**

I don't get any error message, but return my body as null

**Updated2**

```
 this.appService.http.post('http://localhost:2717/api/testAPi/test', "{\"GradeA\" : \"23\", \"GradeB\" : \"45\", \"GradeC\" : \"22\"}", {headers: headers})
```

still not working with different format of the body while Postman works with it

Comment: What do you expect to get from your controller?  Cause right now you will only ever get the strings: "ok" and "error".  **EDIT** OP has edited their code since this comment was made.

Comment: i am expecting to get json_object at the end

Comment: What is the text of the exception? What's the value of body if you debug the method?

Comment: it's null in body and exception just returns "error"

Comment: You should get rid of your `catch` block and look at the actual error.

Comment: sorry, i am not quite familiar with C# environment, can you advice on how to do this?

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa Just remove `catch` part and .NET will take care of showing you the exception on its own.

Comment: it does not throw any error but still returning body as null

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa what is your language? I am almost certainly sure it takes this string and treats it as `"{"GradeA" : "23", "GradeB" : "45", "GradeC" : "22"}"`, as `\"` is the most common way of escaping `"`character, so it can be entered into editor. If you put it in text editor to be compiled, please put it as `"{\\\"GradeA\\\" : \\\"23\\\", \\\"GradeB\\\" : \\\"45\\\", \\\"GradeC\\\" : \\\"22\\\"}"` so you have escaped backslash and escaped `"` char to make them both really be in compiled string and sent to the API.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure it is caused by that you are defining that you are sending JSON (object) - your header shows that to WebAPI:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

and this object is quite complex.
In Controller you are expecting simple string.

You should either:

Move JSON deserializing job to Controller by defining model in method prototype:

```
public string test([FromBody] YourClassResemblingJson body)
{
    ...
}
```

Please look at more detiled information in this matter at: [Post json data in body to web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250810/post-json-data-in-body-to-web-api)

Or just send your JSON as properly formatted string. So JSON that originally looks like this:

```
{"body": "sampleBody"}
```

should look like this:

```
"{\"body\": \"sampleBody\"}"
```

Your code for this would look like this:

```
callServer() { 
    var data = JSON.stringify(test);
    data = "\"" + data.replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";
    //display JSON like "{\"GradeA\" : \"23\", \"GradeB\" : \"45\", \"GradeC\" : \"22\"}" 
    console.log(data);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.appService.http.post('http://localhost:2717/api/testAPi/test', data, {headers: headers})
                    .subscribe(data => {console.log(data), (err) => console.error("Failed! " + err);
     })
}
```

In first approach you'll have `body` object filled with your data from JSON, and in the second approach you'll have correct `string` in your `body` variable.

Sorry for so much editing, but I wasn't sure about what exactly is your problem, so it took me some time to dig up into the WebAPI specifications.

Comment: this actually rings a bell to me, but I get Unsported media type 415 error

Comment: Do you get it before or after my changes?

Comment: sorry, what is YourClassResemblingJson  ?

Comment: and I am not sending JSON object.

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa please take a look at my edit. Of course you were sending JSON object, this is exactly what is your JSON string.

Comment: isn't jsong string and object technically different? I did look at it before. Didn't help.

Comment: the url you referred to, I am looking for the way to work this out without creating modelling name as I will have a lot of data coming from client later on(mentioned in my post)

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa so please take a look at another edit - I've added way to put string into WebAPI. I needed to dig into the specifications, but finally found the way.

Comment: so should I add \ sign in my client side just before sending them? this is not just static data, instead they are being updated from web services.. I guess i have to find a way to insert those sign somehow

Comment: Yes, replace all `"` signs with `\"` and contain whole string in `"` characters (without `\ `). So your example would look exactly like: `"{\"GradeA\" : \"23\", \"GradeB\" : \"45\", \"GradeC\" : \"22\"}"`. Keep in mind, that all `"` characters in grayed area are intentional.

Comment: sounds like that it will work.. i will try but not sure why JSON.stringfiy does not get me the json string

Comment: It gives you the JSON string (just in language which you're using it's string) but overally every JSON string is an object. It's just that some are complex, with brackets, properties, etc and some are simple, that are strings contained in `""`.

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa Open your browser's console window and put in `var x = {"value": 1}`, confirm with Enter (or Return, whatever you call it) key, then put `x` and hit Enter. On FF you'll get `Object { value: 1}`, on other browsers something similar, sometimes object browser for more complex values. It's not without any meaning, that JSON is formely JavaScript Object Notation. Every JSON string is complete and correct JavaScript Object. The only thing making difference between String and Object is your language, as JS doesn't care, so when using JSON, you should stick to JS conventions.

Comment: i see.. but unfortunately this still returns null. I thought this makes sense and it will work out but not working. I literally copied and pasted "{\"GradeA\" : \"23\", \"GradeB\" : \"45\", \"GradeC\" : \"22\"}" in the body message when doing POST

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa where did you paste it? It surely works, I did it, forged request in PostMan and was succesfully received by the WebAPI.

Comment: pleases refer to updated post. Thanks. and I also tried with the Postman. It just works fine without / sign. http://localhost:61476/api/tesApi/report?body={"body":"body", "hi" : "w"} in Postman

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa Did you remove [FromBody] directive?

Comment: No I did not. If I remove FromBody directive, it gives me 404  server error in client side and this was my initial problem. So I just kept it.

Comment: So in postman did you send POST or GET? And why put data in URL?

Comment: i used post... i am not really familiar with Postman, I just clicked Params and I thought this sends as parameter

Comment: You should click on `Body`, select `Raw`, and `JSON` on the right. And put the contents inside. Because it's what request will look like sent from your client.

Comment: why regardless?

Comment: let me check again , give me some time

Comment: Okay, I can confirm with [FromBody] directive, it works fine when sending msg in body with / signs.. now bakc to question is why not working from my client side..

Comment: So you used PostMan, sent backslashed message and worked?
Is your Client JS or what?

Comment: Yes. It is angular 4

Comment: in your data sample do: 
`data = "\"" + data.replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"";`
after JSON.stringify ;)

Let me put your modified code in my answer ;)

Comment: ill try tomorrow and get back to you . Thanks for your time!

Comment: It works perfect! but now i realized that I need to format my json in client like   {"valid":"Check", "Parameters":[{"name":"GradeA", "value":"32"},{"name":"GradeB","value":"44"}]} and I am thinking I should put this in URL else I have to insert \ signs again..

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa putting in URL has more cons than pros. 
First and more important is limited URL length. You shouldn't put too long string in URl, or it might fail. Second one is that URL string has to be escaped too, it just is done automatically, not your code, so in the end URL string has even more unneeded text and is longer. Third one, is that it's just ugly and unprofessional to send data like this. Moreover, if your request changes something on server side (save etc.) not only retrieve response, you SHOULD use POST, not GET.

Answer (score 0):

Very first your API method is `GET` method since that's default but from client you are making a `POST` call. Other than that, the passed data is not getting used anywhere

```
public string test([FromBody] string body)
{
```

Comment: confirmed that it's set to GET

Comment: @ZlatkoLoa, then make a `get` call and remove that `FromBody`. also specify what's error you are getting exactly

Comment: Are you sure you can use `[FromBody]` in GET request? I would rather think `[FromBody]` would just make method POST, as you cannot send body in GET request...

Comment: without Frombody, i get server error code 404. This is from my research. Without this, I can't get my client to connect to my backend at all.

Comment: @Rahul I am definitely sure in .NET Core WebAPI `[FromBody]` attribute makes request POST (I checked it), and like 99% sure for older WebAPIs. So please check your answer.

Comment: @DominikSzymański. it's true ... `FromBody` is used for POST request and not for GET operation and thus suggested OP to remove that. See my comment

Comment: @Rahul and OP is sending POST request and puts data in POST body. Why move the data to URL instead of solving the problem with POST?

Comment: without using [FromBody].... again, I get an server code error 404.. I included my webApiConfig file. Please refer to updated post